# Using mapped tables (JPA) in javafx

Tags: hibernate, jpa, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I've mapped a table

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Immutable
@Entity
@Table(schema = "dbo", name = "tCountry")
public class FaCountry {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CountryID")
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

How can I use it in JavaFX SceneBuilder? I've created a TableView in SceneBuilder and named `fx:id` of this TableView as `countryTable`. I guess I have to create in Main Class

```
private ObservableList<FaCountry> countryData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

and put info from this ObservableList into Controller

```
@FXML
    private TableView<FaCountry> countryTable;
```

But how to put data from mapped table inside this ObservableList? I can't get full picture of how to do that. I'm new to all this topics and Java at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following:

```
            @FXML
            private TableView<FaCountry> countryTable; 
            private ObservableList<FaCountry> countryData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            private EntityManagerFactory emf;
            private EntityManager em;
            //  ...
                public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
                emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceTest");
                em = emf.createEntityManager();
                TypedQuery<FaCountry> query = em.createQuery(
                        "SELECT e FROM FaCountry e", FaCountry.class);
                List<FaCountry> list = query.getResultList();
                countryData.addAll(list);
                countryTable.setItems(countryData);
    }
```